# Как использовать полиморфизм в Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Есть несколько вариантов реализации `DAO` интерфейса. Один из компонентов может принимать в качестве параметра в конструктор этот интерфейс. Но как мне определить для спринга какую реализацию использовать?

```
public interface DAO {
    void add(Item item);
    Item getItem(int id);
}

public class DAOMemory implements DAO {
    private final List<Item> memory;

    public DAOMemory() {
        memory = new ArrayList<>(100);
    }
}

public class DAOJdbc implements DAO {
    @Autowired
    public DAOJdbc(final PropertiesLoader properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

И класс который использует `DAO` :

```
@Component
public class UserManager {

    private final DAO dao;

    //Вот тут проблема. Не понятно какой DAO я собираюсь использовать.
    @Autowired
    public UserStore(final DAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
        ...
}
```

Как как без костылей дать понять Spring, какую реализацию я хочу использовать в каждом конкретном случае? И соответствует ли вообще такой стиль написания кода этому фраемворку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать аннотацию [@Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) с указанием именем бина:

```
@Component
public class UserManager {
    private final DAO dao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("daoJdbc") 
    public UserStore(final DAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    ...
}
```

И в конфигурации контекста этот бин определить:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    ...

    <bean id="daoJdbc" class="com.example.DAOJdbc" />
</beans>
```

Comment: да, мне даже идея ее предлогает, но если я укажу `@Qualifier("daoJdbc")` то как мне использовать реализацию `DAOMemory` ?

Comment: Два варианта: сменить в квалификторе имя или сменить в конфигурации реализацию. Только во втором случае надо имя выбрать обобщённое.

Comment: тоесть я правильно понял что создать два инстанса в одном рантайме я не могу либо либо? (Пардон за наивные вопросы только начал изучать спринг)

Comment: Создать можно, внедрить в **одно** поле нет.

Comment: а я могу задать отдельную реализацию для юнит тестов? Так что бы если я запускаю тест у меня использовался `DAOMemory` а при запуске программы `DAOJdbc`? Нет ли случайно такой возможности?

Comment: У Spring достаточно развитая [система тестирования](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html), позволяющая в тестах использовать отдельную конфигурацию, тестовые профили, переопределять отдельные части конфигурации и мóкать объекты.